# Listening to updates in an Array of Objects in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, combine

I'm working on a project where I need to listen to any changes in an array of objects. By changes I refer:

1. Add/Remove element in the array
2. Any change in the existing array elements

Here is the sample code,

```
enum DownloadState {
    case queued
    case completed
}

class DownloadTask: ObservableObject {
    var downloadState: DownloadState = .queued
}

class DownloadManager {
    var downloadTasks = [DownloadTask]()
}
```

In the above code, `DownloadManager` contains an array of `DownloadTask`. I want to listen to the changes when,

1. A new `DownloadTask` instance is added into `downloadTasks` array
2. An existing `DownloadTask` instance is removed from `downloadTasks` array
3. The underlying `DownloadState` is changed for a particular `DownloadTask` in `downloadTasks` array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach that worked for us:

**1.** Create a protocol to listen to any changes in the `DownloadTask`

```
public protocol DownloadStateHandlerDelegate: AnyObject {
    func didUpdateDownloadState(title: String, downloadState: DownloadState)
}
```

**2.** Passed the `delegate` instance to the `DownloadManager` during initialization.

```
class DownloadManager {
    private weak var delegate: DownloadStateHandlerDelegate?
    private var downloadTasks = [DownloadTask]()

    init(delegate: DownloadStateHandlerDelegate) {
        self.delegate = delegate
    }
}
```

**3.** Called the `delegate` method `didUpdateDownloadState` whenever the `downloadState` of a `DownloadTask` is updated.

**Example:**

```
class DownloadTask {
    @Published private var downloadState: DownloadState {
        didSet {
            self.delegate?.didUpdateDownloadState(title: self.title, downloadState: self.downloadState)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible approach is to make task a value type and manager as `ObservableObject` with published property for array of tasks, like

```
struct DownloadTask {
    var downloadState: DownloadState = .queued
}

class DownloadManager: ObservableObject {
    @Published var downloadTasks = [DownloadTask]()
}
```

So requested changes can be observed either via `@ObservedObject` wrapper in SwiftUI view or via `manager.$downloadTasks` publisher in any other place.

Comment: If we just observe the `downloadTasks`, how will we get the delta of what is changed?